# ASP.NET : get value from url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to get a value from the URL and save it to a value but any attempt I've made has failed.

Here is an example of the URL:

```
https://localhost:44325/deals/PostDeal?id=101
```

I want to save the value of `id` to `DealsMasters.DealItemID`.

Here is what I have been working with

```
string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}",
                               HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);

var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(baseUrl.Query);

var var2 = query.Get("var2");

DealsMasters.DealItemID = var2;
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you mean `query.Get("id")` instead of `query.Get("var2")`?

Comment: Hi @Xerillio thanks for your reply. im still getting two errors in my code from changing "VAR2" to "id". ive updated my question to include a screenshot of the code and the errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating it more than necessary. `HttpContext.Request` already has a [`QueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8) property you can get the individual parameters from:

```
var idParam = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"];
DealsMasters.DealItemID = int.Parse(idParam); // Note: this will fail if 'id' is not an integer
```

---

To address the errors you see:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Query' [...]

The `baseUrl` you have defined is a [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) and strings do not have a `Query` property so you cannot do `baseUrl.Query`.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

`query.Get("id")` returns a string, since all parts of a URL are handled as strings. If you know that part of the URL is an integer, you need to convert/parse it, such as using [`int.Parse(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8#system-int32-parse(system-string)) like I did above.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a parameter which name is id to OnPostAsync:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
    DealsMasters.DealItemID = id;
    ...
}
```